# Create customer custom attribute checkbox in edit form backend

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, customer-attribute, checkbox

I added my customer attribute.

[image]

But I want to display these fields as checkboxes. I created checkbox in the frontend easily but the backend is not. And then save to the database. Please help me. Thanks.

my script

```
<?php
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'biz_confirmation', array(
    'label'     => 'Business Customer Confirmation',
    'type'      => 'int',
    'input'     => 'checkbox',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => true,
    'default'   => '0',
));
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'marketing_consent', array(
    'label'     => 'Marketing Consent',
    'type'      => 'int',
    'input'     => 'checkbox',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => false,
    'default'   => '0',
));
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'b2b_contact_consent', array(
    'label'     => 'B2B Contact Consent',
    'type'      => 'int',
    'input'     => 'checkbox',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => false,
    'default'   => '0',
));
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'biz_confirmation_time', array(
    'label'     => 'Business Customer Confirmation Update Time',
    'type'      => 'datetime',
    'input'     => 'datetime',
    'visible'   => false,
    'required'  => false,
));
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'mkt_consent_updated_time', array(
    'label'     => 'Marketing Consent Update Time',
    'type'      => 'datetime',
    'input'     => 'datetime',
    'visible'   => false,
    'required'  => false,
));
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'b2b_consent_updated_time', array(
    'label'     => 'B2B Contact Consent Update Time',
    'type'      => 'datetime',
    'input'     => 'datetime',
    'visible'   => false,
    'required'  => false,
));
$attributeCodes = array(
    'biz_confirmation',
    'marketing_consent',
    'b2b_contact_consent',
    'biz_confirmation_time',
    'mkt_consent_updated_time',
    'b2b_consent_updated_time'
);

foreach($attributeCodes as $code) {
    $attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('customer', $code);
    $used_in_forms = array(
        'adminhtml_customer',
        'checkout_register',
        'customer_account_create',
        'customer_account_edit');
    $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);
    $attribute->save();
}
```

Comment: please send your script code .

Comment: @Shorabh i updated

Answer (score 0):

Try `boolean` instead of `checkbox`.

```
 'input' => 'boolean',
```

**Reference:** https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Customer-custom-attribute-with-checkbox-input-throws-exception/m-p/78907/highlight/true#M3323